# Storyboard initializing UIView instead of my custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uistoryboard

I have a custom class called `NumberView` which subclasses `UIScrollView`. I put a `UIView` onto my storyboard and changed the class to `NumberView`:

[image: Screenshot of storyboard]

I then created an outlet to my `ShotTraceViewController` class:

```
@interface ShotTraceViewController () 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NumberView *numberView;
@end
```

I've defined a few methods in the `NumberView.h` and `NumberView.m`:

.h:

```
@interface NumberView : UIScrollView
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<NumberViewDelegate> number_delegate;
-(void)setTotalBtns:(int)total;
...
@end
```

.m:

```
@interface NumberView ()
@end
@implementation NumberView {
}
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    return self;
}
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    return self;
}
-(void)setTotalBtns:(int)total {
    NSLog(@"Setting buttons");
}
@end
```

But when I try to call `[self.numberView setTotalBtns:3];` from my `ShotTraceViewController`. I get an exception:

> -[UIView setTotalBtns:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x104fad3e0

Whoa! That's not right, it's supposed to be a `NumberView` not a `UIView`! Am I doing something wrong?

I've also noticed that initWithFrame and initWithCoder are both not being called.

Comment: In you init from Storyboard then `initWithFrame:` shouldn't be called but `initWithCoder:` might be. Could you post your screenshot? It doesn't seem as the error say that you put correctly its class to the view.

Comment: Updated. Sorry, somehow my screenshot got detached.

Comment: "But when I try to call [self.numberView setTotalBtns:3]; from my ShotTraceViewController" Please show _how_ you do that, in actual context. Also please log `self.numberView` at that time so we can find out more about what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this worked, but unchecking the `Inherit Module from Target` button underneath the class selection fixed everything.